# Search Conversations in "Office Groups"

Tags: search, sharepoint, office365

In Office365 we have created several groups in our "Office Group" (part of Office Graph). I want to use a web part in SharePoint to query for conversations, sort by date (desc), and display the results in a web part on our SharePoint landing page (Intranet start page).

Is still possible? (I know Office Groups are quite new in O365).
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question.  Office 365 REST APIs don't yet support retrieving conversations for a Group.  This is on our roadmap, but I don't yet have a timeline to share with you.  Hope that helps.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Thx for you comment, but noticed the [Graph Query Language (GQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/query-Office-graph-using-gql-with-search-rest-api). Is be possible to use that for query Office Graph (since Office Groups is part of Office Graph) and use the filter functionality in GQL to filter only relevant results?

Comment: Hi Henrik, Searching Office Graph wouldn't provide you Group conversations yet.  Stay tuned as Groups support is high on our roadmap and we are working through it.  Hope that helps.